# using a std::vector<Particle> particles; function .at() not working with iterator it as parameter inside a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, vector

```
class Particles {
    constexpr static int particleNum = 25;
    constexpr static double gravity = 1.1;
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
    std::vector<Particle>::iterator it = particles.begin();
};
```

I am trying to create the 25 particles that are specified above and for that I'm using the `it` iterator in the for loop which works fine but when the `particles.at(it)` is used the console outputs an error code that says:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::vector::at(std::vector::iterator&)'
>                if (!particles.at(it).life){

I have tried using a simple integer for this task but then I have the `particles.erase(it)` not working as it needs an it_&; just take a look:

```
Particles::Particles(sf::RenderWindow& renderWindow, int x, int y) {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= particleNum; i++){
        particles.push_back(Particle(x, y));
    }

    do{
        for(; it <= particles.end();){
            if (!particles.at(it).life){
                it = particles.erase(it);
            }else{
                particles.at(it).update();
                it++;
            }
            renderWindow.draw(particles.at(it).particleShape);
        }
    }while(!particles.empty());
    // to change later for different effects:
}
```

Comment: `particles.at(it)` is not supposed to work: `at()` takes an index, not an iterator. You want `it->life`, `it->update()` and so on. Also, the loop condition should be `it != particles.end()`. `particles.end()` is a one-past-the-last iterator; it's not dereferenceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying the code you have created beyond your context, the`do while` loop can be done like so:

```
unsigned int ctr = 0;
do{
    for(; it != particles.end(); ++it){
        ++ctr;
        if (!particles.at(ctr).life){
            it = particles.erase(it); //keep in mind erase invalidates all iterators from [it:end)
        }else{
            particles.at(ctr).update();
            it++;
        }

    }
}while(!particles.empty());
```

Additionally, there's a few other ways you could achieve the desired effect. For example, using just the counter instead, and using `particles.begin() + ctr` to specify the offset; with proper checks of course that it isn't beyond `particles.end()`. Another option instead of using at, is to access the iterator if not end as well. For example:

```
do{
    for(; it != particles.end(); ++it){

        if (!it->life){
            particles.erase(it); //erase this item here
            it = particles.begin(); //reinitialize the iterator to beginning to continue searching
        }
        else{
            it->update();
            it++;
        }

    }
}while(!particles.empty());
```

Otherwise, yet another possibility is to call `particles.back().update()` as required and use `pop_back` after the `update` call, or once checking to see if you need to remove it is completed.

There are probably other more/less obvious ways to do the same thing as well.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick answer and help! I tried it and it works and compiles it's just that i have problems in other parts of my system which makes it crash when i try to update the particles and I was wondering where I can post my files so you can help me more because i'm 16 and I have only taken a programming class once and it was in VB and did some C# file manipulation program so i'm not good at all in c++ apart from some basic apps. Took me hours just to get my cMakeLists to work well. Sorry for asking a noobish question like this i'm new to this site.

Comment: I know the feeling -- I started when I was 11 and now have a career in the field. Best part of programming is: there's more than 1 right way to do something. As for getting me files to look at and what not -- I would look into getting a github account and posting them there. I'm sure there are other services out there as well. Then link in your profile and of course, post here asking questions.

Comment: ok thanks, I just created a github account and uploaded my project, the repository adress is : https://github.com/saidmetiche2000/untitled1 and I'm using c++11 and MinGW 5.0 just in case. If you can help it would be really nice I have tried getting particles to show up for more than 3 days now and I wanna get to drawing tiles and making grids as my final goal is to make a tic tac toe game

Comment: I thought making a tic tac toe game would be easy but it's really hard after all. Not like VB or even JS with canvases from where I followed a tutorial and could easily make particles. it's way harder using sfml and c++. also pointers confuse me a lot

Comment: @DanielSooSkinny Found ya, and did some fixing for you. Check your pull request. Let's continue discussion there. I'll help with what I can.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an `iterator` to the `at` method, but [that method has a parameter of type `size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), not `std::vector::iterator&`. You need to call the method with a simple index, not an iterator.

Comment: "I have tried using a simple integer for this task but then I have the .erase() function not working as it needs an it_&"